# How to set TWO first words of a slider header with a different color using variables in php?

Tags: php, colors, slider, title, cpu-word

There is a template https://wordpress.org/themes/bizberg/.

In "Customize" the slider title type is adjustable, and the title's first word color could be replaced with a theme color.
BUT there's no sense to set a different color on an article “the” in sentence "The world is beautiful". It should be at least first TWO words “The Future”, “The World” etc.

ANY IDEAS HOW TO MAKE IT WORK?

Thank you in advance!

(php code is below)

**functions.php:**

```
return '<h1 class="slider_title_layout_' . $slider_title_layout . ' ' . $slider_text_align . '">' .  '<span class="firstword">'.$title[0].'</span>'.substr(implode(" ", $title), strlen($title[0])) . '</h1>';
```

**front-page-hero.php:**

```
array(
            'element'  => '.slider_title_layout_3 .firstword,.slider_title_layout_4 .lastword',
            'property' => 'color'
        ),
```

Comment: Replace both occurrences of `$title[0]` with `$title[0].' '.$title[1]`. (That might give faulty results of course, if you ever had a title that was one word only.)

Comment: Did you replace _both_ occurences? Otherwise, it will not determine correctly how much to cut off of the full, imploded words again.

Comment: @CBroe That was the reason - I replaced only one at first!

Thank you VERY MUCH for the tip! It worked. TOTALLY!  (https://hunger-hilfe.de/en/)

Comment: @CBroe Now the question is - how to make it work only on certain pages, where the article is on first position... Guess, I gotta add the layout choice for every slide into customization panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@CBroe**'s tip!

"Replace both occurrences of $title[0] with $title[0].' '.$title[1]."

It worked wonderfully!

Also I've received a perfect answer from **@Sergei Kirjanov**.

So if you need to highlight a few title words only in certain slides, put the " ^ " sign after necessary words and change the php-code for :

```
$title = explode( strpos($title, "^") ? "^" : " ", $title );
```

It says, if a string has "^" then separate the colored title part after it, otherwise as usual after the space " ".